# Sorting on a page

Tags: pagination, sort

When the results are displayed across pages and say you are on nth page and try to sort on a column, should it remain on the same nth page or should it display the first page?
If it can be either, are there use cases/specific kind of data when it would be ideal to stay on the current page upon sorting vs. navigate back to the first page?

Comment: It should go back to the first page. Makes no sense to stay on the current as its content (i.e. the items it presents) may change anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You should navigate back to the first page. To understand why, you should simply answer the question why user sort lists. For example they want to :

- find the highest score
- start reviewing products starting from the lowest price
- find the most recent posts
- find the employee name starting with the letter B
- find the e-mails send on the 5th of December

In all of the above cases, the most useful behavior would be to navigate back to the first page.

Comment: An exception could be if you've selected/chosen one item in the list and wish to see its position under another sort e.g. a list of football players sorted by appearance count, christiano ronaldo is selected, and then the list is re-sorted by transfer fee. In that case it makes sense to pivot the sort around that item such that you go straight to the page that item is on.

Comment: I'd argue that that example defies a sort/pagination convention in service of a bad multi-select list view pattern.  If the searcher truly needs to execute multiple sorts to select multiple players, then they might be better served by a shopping cart coupled with a single-select list interface.